# 3-particle phase space in $d$ dimensions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics, phase-space

recently I came across a problem concerning the 3-particle phase space. I am trying to show, that the 3-particle phase space for massless particles with momenta $p_1$, $p_2$ and $k$ is given by

$$
d\Phi_3=\frac{s^{1-2\epsilon}}{16(2\pi)^3}\frac{(4\pi)^{2\epsilon}}{\Gamma(2-2\epsilon)}\frac{dx_1dx_2}{[(1-x_1)(1-x_2)(1-x_3)]^{\epsilon}},
$$

where I start with

$$
d\Phi_3=\frac{1}{8(2\pi)^{2d-3}}(p_1^0)^{d-3}(p_2^0)^{d-3}\frac{1}{k^0}dp_1^0dp_2^0d\Omega_1^{d-3}d\Omega_2^{d-2}(1-\cos^2(\theta_{12}))^{\frac{d-4}{2}}d\cos(\theta_{12})\delta(p_1^0+p_2^0+k^0-\sqrt{s}).
$$

To clarify notation: $d=4-2\epsilon$, $\theta_{12}$ is the angle of $\vec{p_2}$ with respect to $\vec{p_1}$, $x_i=\frac{2p_i^0}{\sqrt{s}}$ and $d\Omega^{d-1}$ is an element of solid angle for the surface of the d dimensional unit ball.

First of all: Is this formula correct?

For the $\cos(\theta_{12})$ part, I stick to the instructions provided here: https://www.ippp.dur.ac.uk/~krauss/Lectures/QuarksLeptons/Basics/PS_2.html
Therefore I get after integration

$$
(1-\cos^2(\theta_{12}))^{\frac{d-4}{2}}d\cos(\theta_{12})\delta(p_1^0+p_2^0+k^0-\sqrt{s})\frac{1}{k^0}=(1-u_0^2)^{-\epsilon}\frac{4}{x_1x_2s}
$$

with $u_0=\frac{2}{x_1x_2}+x_1+x_2-1-\frac{1}{2}x_1x_2$.

What I am finally left with is

$$
d\Phi_3=\frac{s^{1-2\epsilon}}{16(2\pi)^3}\frac{(4\pi)^{2\epsilon}}{\Gamma(2-2\epsilon)}\left(\frac{2}{x_1x_2}\right)^{\epsilon}dx_1dx_2[1-u_0^2]^{-\epsilon}.
$$

Looks rather similar to the desired result, but I cannot manage the final steps in my calculation. Any suggestions how to deal with this problem?